# Fraction Simplification

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a program that reduces Fractions to their simplest form but it is only partially working (simplifying the numerator by the proper amount but leaving the denominator the same), can somebody help me understand what is failing?

```
private int greatestCommonDivisor(int num1, int num2) {
    
    while(num1-num2!=0) {
        if(num1>num2) {
            num1 = num1 - num2;
        }
        else {
            num2 = num2 - num1;
        }
    }
    
    return num1;
    
}
private void simplify() {
    if(denominator<0) {
        numerator = numerator*(-1);
        denominator = denominator*(-1);
    }
    else {
        numerator = numerator/greatestCommonDivisor(numerator, denominator);
        denominator = denominator/greatestCommonDivisor(numerator, denominator);
    }
}
public String toString() {
    simplify();
    if(denominator == 1) {
        return numerator + "";
    }
    else if(numerator!=0) {
        return numerator + "/" + denominator;
    }
    else {
        return "0";
    }
    
}
```

I believe that is all the necessary information, definitely let me know if you need something else.

Comment: In `simplify` you're modifying `numerator` and then using it as a parameter to a method call. You may want to save the result of calling `greatestCommonDivisor` before you modify its params.

Comment: Thank you so much, that makes sense.